# Add headers to a Django redirect

Tags: django, amazon-s3, http-redirect

I am returning a file to the client via `redirect(s3_url)`. According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#setting-header-fields) I should be able to add a custom header:

```
response = redirect(s3_url)
response['File-Name'] = file_name
return response
```

In chrome dev tools, I don't see any `File-Name` header in the response headers.

Comment: Are you sure you inspect the headers of the redirect response, and not of the response after the request is made to the URL to redirect to?

Comment: A redirect simply returns a response with the URI to go to, it is up to the browser to contact the `s3_url`, and of course the response headers of *that* request will be different.

Comment: I was prob inspecting the s3 response. How can I inspect the redirect response from dev tools?

Comment: probably using a tool like `curl` is easier, but you can try to (temporarily) disable the redirect: https://www.wikihow.com/Block-Page-Redirects